# How to format a list of listings heading as section NOT as chapter (report class)

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, listings

in my thesis I have a few R scripts at the very end, as an Appendix. Within the appendix itself I want the `\lstlistoflistings`.

This formats the list as a chapter (same as for the toc).

How can I format it as section?
I just want to avoid the page break after the chapter title and have the list right after it, with a smaller font.

Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass{report}  

\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{language=R}
    \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of R scripts}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{the first chapter}
    \section{section1}
some text
\chapter{the second chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\lstlistoflistings

\newpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A script]
some code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another script]
some more code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load `tocbasic` and `scrhack`. Then you can use `\setuptoc{lol}{leveldown}`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\setuptoc{lol}{leveldown}

\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{language=R}
    \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of R scripts}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{the first chapter}
    \section{section1}
some text
\chapter{the second chapter}
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A script]
some code
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another script]
some more code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have changed the order of `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline` to get the right page number in ToC.

Answer (score 2):

`\lstlistoflistings` (what a easy to remember name ;-)) uses `\tableofcontents` internally actually and redefines `\@starttoc` slightly to apply, but still has the `\chapter*` heading of `\tableofcontents`.

In my point of view, it's easier to apply a redefinition of `\lstlistoflistings` such that it has the same appearance as `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=R}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of R scripts}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
  \begingroup
  \clearpage
  \section*{\lstlistlistingname% Taken from `article.cls`....
   \@mkboth{%
     \MakeUppercase\lstlistlistingname}{\MakeUppercase   
     \lstlistlistingname}
   }%
  \@starttoc{lol}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{the first chapter}
\section{section1}
some text
\chapter{the second chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\lstlistoflistings

\newpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A script]
some code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another script]
some more code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]